# Manipulating c# objects through Java

Tags: java, wcf, adt, ksoap

I'm writing an application in Java/Android.In my application I consume a wcf web service
using KSOAP2.My problem is that there are times that instead of a single string I could receive an object (or arrays of objects) which are defined in the c# web services.Is there any way I can process these objects?If it helps I can tell you that I know how the classes of these objects are defined in the c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured this out in fact I found out 2 articles about it with really explicit tutorials I will just post them here in case anyone stumbles upon this post [link](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.gr/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html?commentPage=2) and [link](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.gr/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can process these objects?

Define "process". Using webservices, you transmit serialized objects, which are (usually) an XML representation of the objects in the language at either end (service or client).

If you define a class `Person` with a property `Name`, you can return an object of this class from a service. The client consuming this service will have to use a framework or built-in mechanism to deserialize the service classes to objects.

You'll probably have to generate classes for those objects in Java, using the WSDL the C# service generates.

Comment: well sorry i didn't mean to be ambiguous.Since i said I'm using KSOAP2 i meant that the messages between my client and the server are 
serialized/deserialized in an XML format.In case that an object is a simple string or integer etc my app has no problem deserializing it.But there are classes that are designed in the server and are more complicated.What I meant "process" is a way to map these objects in Java objects (meaning: objects my app will have no problem reading their data)

Comment: @user1514105 I have no experience with ksoap, but will [this](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2ksoap/) help?

Comment: Well i download this but it doesn't seem helpful.What I should do is find a way to reconstruct the serialized object from C# into a Java object after I have deserialized it.

Comment: @user1514105 in order to do that, you'll have to create a Java class that represents the format of the serialized class that the C# service publishes. In order to generate such classes from a WSDL (which the service exposes), you can use the [tool](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2ksoap/) I just linked.

Comment: but i already know the architecture of these classes.Is this tool providing more info on the transformation?Also, have you ever used it?what should enter in the field of package?

Comment: @user1514105 as I said I don't know the toolchain for ksoap so I can't help you with that. All I know is to deserialize an object, you have to have a class for that object. If you post relevant Java code, perhaps someone can help.

Comment: Well I completly understand.But you my problem isn't in any specific block of code as I said before i can deserialize simple strings.I don't know how i can ''re-create'' those objects..